# The kernel of a morphism of co-rings is a co-ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras, comodules

I would like to show that

> The Kernel of a coring morphism $\phi:C\rightarrow C'$ between two $R$-corings $(C,\Delta,\epsilon)$ and $(C',\Delta',\epsilon')$ is a coideal.

The only point that I can't show is that $$\Delta(\text{Ker}(\phi))\subset \text{Ker}(\pi\otimes\pi)$$

This should be straightforward but I can't show it.

**EDIT:**

$\pi$ is the natural projection of $C$ unto $C/\text{Ker}(\phi)$

The definition I use are

A coring morphism from an $R$-coring $(C,\Delta,\epsilon)$ to another $R$-coring $(C',\Delta',\epsilon')$ is a $R$-bimodule morphism $\phi$ such that $\epsilon'\circ\phi = \epsilon$ and $(\phi\otimes\phi)\circ\Delta = \Delta'\circ\phi$.

A coideal $I$ of the $R$-coring $C$ is a $R$-subbimodule of $C$ such that $I\subset \text{Ker}(\epsilon)$ and 
        \begin{align*}
        \Delta(I) \subset \text{Ker}(\pi\otimes\pi)
    \end{align*}
        where $\pi:C\rightarrow C/I$ is the cannonical projection map.

Comment: What is $\pi$ here?

Comment: Sorry, $\pi$ is the natural projection of $C$ unto $C/\text{Ker}(\phi)$

Comment: Since you are speaking generally about corings (and not especially about coalgebras) could you please make explicit the definition of the notion of co-ideal you are using ?

Answer (score 3):

The statement:

> The Kernel of a coring morphism $\phi:C\rightarrow C'$ between two $R$-coring's $(C,\Delta,\epsilon)$ and $(C',\Delta',\epsilon')$ is a coideal.

is not true in general:

- It is true if one considers the special **case of coalgebras over a field $k$** (a proof of this, can be found at [Hopf algebras: an introduction](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Hopf_Algebra.html?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&redir_esc=y),  Dascalescu et al, p. 25-26, proposition 1.4.9),
- However, in **the general case that we have an $A$-coring $C$** instead of a coalgebra over a field $k$ (now the linear structure of $C$ is that of an $A$-bimodule ${}_AC_A$, where $A$ is an arbitrary -that is: non-commutative in general- algebra) the statement is not valid as it is: In this case, the coideal is by definition the kernel of a surjective $A$-coring morphism (and not of any $A$-coring morphism). For this last case, see the proof and futher details at: [Corings and Comodules](https://books.google.gr/books?id=Ea1EeaOu_HUC&lpg=PP1&hl=el&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), Brzezinski et al, proposition 17.14, p. 177-178.
  The same situation holds in the case of **coalgebras over a commutative ring $R$** (for a proof of the case where the "scalars" are elements of a commutative ring $R$, see: [Corings and Comodules](https://books.google.gr/books?id=Ea1EeaOu_HUC&lpg=PP1&hl=el&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), Brzezinski et al.,  proposition 2.4, p. 9-10)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I am taking my statement from a paper by Sweedler "The prequel to the Jacobson-Bourbaki theorem" where it is clearly stated that the kernel of a coring morphism is a coideal. I'll put the definitions as an edit

Comment: @tomak: thank you for your edit. It contributes to clarifying the problem. However, i tried a little search on the Sweedler's paper you are citing and i was not able to find it online. Could you add some link to it?

Comment: I got the pdf from my teacher. Any way I could send it to you?

Comment: Could you possibly use an upload-a-file-to-share facility, such as for example: https://expirebox.com and share the corresponding link here?

Comment: @tomak: you could also send me an email. I d' be glad to take a look at the paper you are citing. Of course you should also ask your teacher ;)